# 2 Inner divs - one should be center and not collide with the other

Tags: html, css

I have a situation when I have a parent div and 2 inner divs.
The first inner div **should always be at the left-top**, while the second div should be at **the center of the parent div**.

At first, div that should be at center wasn't at the true center of the parent div, but at the center of the gap that left between the first div and the end of the container:

[image]

To fix it I've made the first div absolute so it will be ignored:

[image]

But when I squeeze the container, they collide, instead of the centered div be down to the absolute element. Its probably because the absolute div is not taking into consideration, but I wonder if there is any way I can make it not collide.

This is my case:

[image]

And this is the desired case:

[image]

The parent element has:

```
text-align: center;
```

The blue element has:

```
display: block;
```

The red element has:

```
position: absolute;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think best option is to use `media queries`.

Comment: Can you post your code please? I think you can make a good approach with `flexbox` and `flex-wrap: wrap` property.